# Adding react-lds import in react component resulting in failed compilation

Tags: reactjs

Please refer import that is causing error.It compiles without any issue if I comment this line.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {returnCurrencies} from '../reducers/reducer_currency';
import {DropdownMenu, DropdownMenuList, DropdownMenuListItem} from 'react-lds';

export default class CurrencyDropDown extends Component
{
   constructor(props)
   {
      super(props);
      //console.log("props",props);
   }
   renderCurrencies(curr)
   {
      //console.log("Curr ", curr);
      return (<option key={curr} value={curr}>{curr}</option>);
   }
   render()
   {
      if(!this.props.currencies)
      {
        return (<div></div>);
      }
      let currencyList = returnCurrencies(this.props.currencies);
       return (<div>
          <select value={this.props.initValue} onChange=
              {this.props.selectCurrency}>
            {currencyList.map(this.renderCurrencies)}
          </select>
        </div>);
 }
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "redux-simple-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple starter package for Redux with React and Babel support",
   "main": "index.js",
   "repository": "",
   "scripts": {
       "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
       "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
       "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "devDependencies": {
 "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
 "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
 "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
 "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
 "chai": "^3.5.0",
 "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
 "jquery": "^2.2.1",
 "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
 "mocha": "^2.4.5",
 "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
 "webpack": "^1.12.9",
 "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
},
"dependencies": {
"axios": "^0.16.2",
"babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
"lodash": "^3.10.1",
"prop-types": "^15.5.10",
"react": "^0.14.9",
"react-dom": "^0.14.9",
"react-lds": "^1.1.11",
"react-redux": "4.3.0",
"react-router": "^2.0.1",
"redux": "^3.0.4",
"redux-promise": "^0.5.3"
}
```

}

Failed to compile with below error.

ERROR in ./~/moment-timezone/data/packed/latest.json
Module parse failed: C:..\XXXX\node_modules\moment-timezone\data\packed\latest.json Unexpected token (2:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:10)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (C:..\XXXX\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:..\XXXX\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (C:..\XXXX\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (C:..\XXXX\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:..\XXXX\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (C:..\XXXX\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:..\XXXX\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:709:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (C:..\XXXX\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (C:..\XXXX\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (C:..\XXXX\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3098:39)
 @ ./~/moment-timezone/index.js 2:15-51

Comment: How do you import the module? Can you show your code and not just the error messages?

Comment: updated with code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because it can not load the JSON file. You need to configure webpack to load the JSON files:

Install the `json-loader`:

```
npm install --save-dev json-loader
```

And adjust your webpack config loaders section to use something like this:

```
rules: [
  ...
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    use: 'json-loader'
  }
  ...
]
```

Given that you are using the webpack v1 config may look a bit different to you.

Comment: Making this change in webpack.config.js worked for me.                                                module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    },
     {include: /\.json$/, loaders: ["json-loader"]}
  ]
  }